# SharePoint CA Not Going to Default.aspx

Tags: central-administration, iis

All, I've been dealing with this issue for several days now.  When I hit our Central Admin site `http://abc.gov:47855` I'm getting HTTP 403 Forbidden (see image below) however, I am able to hit CA by adding `http://abc.gov:47855/default.aspx`.  So it's not permissions, right?  It does not take me there on it's own.

Interestingly, everything works w/ default.aspx manually accessed except when I click on an SSP I get the same problem, HTTP 403 and I have to add `/default.aspx`.

I've ensured IIS has `default.aspx` set as the default document.  I have checked permissions on the Virtual Directory and in the Config database.  I also ran SQL Profile on the config database but did not encounter any errors.  Lastly, I did check the log files and didn't see any errors related.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to attach the image.

Comment: @rjcup3 got it-- thx

Comment: Not that that helps much unfortunately... have you checked the web.config (the defaultUrl="x" property of the authentication provider)?

Comment: @rjcup3 yeah I did and we don't have that property in the auth provider in the Virtual Directory 47855 web.config.  I did add it but still experience the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seemed to have tried the basics all you can really do is trace to see where the error is. It is perhaps a security authentication issue or something akin.

In order to determine have a look at [Trouble shooting failed requests - Tracing in IIS7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-70/) this should help you find out what the reason is. (The example is for a 404.2 but this can be used for any failed request)

Comment: ah, a path I shall indeed take.